Valid/Ready based streaming interface: Should control signals be registered?
There are variants of the control signals of streaming interfaces but basically there are two signals. One from the source is usually called valid. One from the data sink is called ready. The streaming interface is a point-to-point interface for data transfer. The sink registers data when both signals are asserted. The source updates its data to the next word when both signals are asserted.
If the control signals are registered then what can happen is that ready is actually deasserted 1 clock cycle after the sink can no longer receive data. This is because in cycle n-1, the combinatorial signal ready is deasserted and then cycle n, it is registered and reaches the data source. This will cause the data source to transmit one extra word of data before it stops. This data will most likely be lost.
A similar issue can happen on the data source. If the data source can no longer transmit data, its internal combinatorial valid will be deasserted in cycle n-1, the registered signal will reach the data sink in cycle n. However, by then the sink will have registered one extra word at its input which was not even valid data.
A simple solution to this problem is actually to use combinatorial control signals directly rather than register them. This is actually a simple solution and can work in theory. However, in practice timing problems occur when multiple modules with streaming interfaces are connected in a long chain. This is because when the data sink on far end deasserts its' ready, it causes a domino affect in that the ready of all the previous modules that feed it, must be deasserted so the whole chain stops moving data through it! The timing problem occurs because we get a critical path of all the module's ready signal in a large combinatorial chain.
In practice it might also be worth making the valid dependant on ready, so that valid is always deasserted when ready is asserted. This will require them to be combinatorial signals as well.
Now my question to the experts is, what is way out of this conundrum? Or maybe I have misunderstood something about this way of exchanging data.

My solution was to develop a module I call "two-stage FIFO". One of its primary applications is to break long combinatorial READY chains when they occur. Otherwise, I do nothing special with the ready-valid handshake.

I am quite surprised that something that looks so simple can be potently complex to design reliably.

In answer to your question, at least for AXI/AXI-S you ordinarily don't add registers to VALID (and data) or READY unless you need to pipeline them to meet timing.
If you need to do that, you will also need to add a 'skid buffer' (small FIFO) to deal with the VALID to not-READY latency in order to prevent the overrun case you describe. The skid buffer FIFO would be sized based on your latency, but it will be at least two entries.
More here: https://mnemocron.github.io/2024-01-22-Skidbuffer/
Related: AXI Stream Pipeline
If you are crossing clock domains that are not synchronized you need a different approach. You would add a FIFO to your slave that has an 'almost full' signal to generate READY. Then the receive FIFO deals with the skid data since there's extra space to catch it.

Very interesting! Even though I developed it entirely on my own, the logic of my "two-stage FIFO" is virtually identical to that of the "skid buffer".

I did the same when I needed to get better timing closure to an external I/O device.

Is there an analytical method to know where the skid buffer should be added i.e should it be added to every single module that uses streaming interface regardless of how small it is or used sparingly?

Also, the answer from the experts on this question implies that the valid and ready must really be combinatorial but the skid buffer can be used to solve the timing problem.

The answer to whether you need a skid buffer or not is exactly as I stated: if your VALID+data and/or READY have additional pipe stages, you need to add a skid. Otherwise, you don't.

I agree that the control signals are better to not be registered so there is no delay between when they are supposed to be asserted/deasserted and when they are actually asserted/deasserted
